# SF short story where animals are genetically engineered to have hands and hunt hunters with guns

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, genetic-engineering

I'm trying to find the title and author of a short story I read about 15 years ago. Some genius genetically modifies animals to have hands and they are given guns. Humans are invited on a hunting trip and the humans are hunted by the armed animals.

Has anyone come across this story before?

Comment: While there are certainly enough details here for someone who has read the story to recall it, can you think of anything else? The more details, the better. Sometimes particularly distinctive details can enable even those users who have not read the story to find it.

Comment: This story came from a book called *[Sexual Chemistry: Sardonic Tales of Genetic Revolution](http://www.philsp.com/stableford/collections/sexual_chemistry.htm)* by Brian Stableford. I can’t recall the story name however.

Comment: @TuiCook Paging through the descriptions of those stories, I don't see a match. Maybe you could check your copy?

Answer (score 9):

At a rough guess, and I don't have the story in front of me, but I think it may be the short story "[*Animal Lover*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?46225)" from "*Daughter of Regals*" by Stephen R Donaldson.

[image: Book Cover - "Daughter of Regals"]

In the story:

> ...an animal-loving special agent cyborg is forced to face down genetically altered animals carrying weapons...

Here's a link to a discussion about the story (Spoiler Alert): [KevinsWatch, Animal Lover](http://kevinswatch.ihugny.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=23904).

Comment: Unnecessary image... isn't it standard to add an image of the book in case it prompts recognition by the querent?

Comment: I have the story and it matches the description in the question so I'd say this is the correct answer. Thanks for answering and please ignore any negative statements in the comments.

Comment: As a small warning - Your link to the discussion prompts malware security alerts for me.

Answer (score -2):

Tc Boyle. Something from the short stories that has the [Descent of Man](https://www.tcboyle.com/books/book_1.html).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please provide the name of a particular story and details from it so we can see how it matches; you should read [answer].